# Using R rvest to scrape a page for number of comments

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape a webpage with R package `rvest` to get the number of comments left on the article. The page uses disqus forum, and disqus returns the number of comments dynamically.

For example for this [webpage](http://www.theonlinecitizen.com/2015/11/3-tips-to-determine-a-good-value-buy-in-current-market-conditions), below the header there is a line that shows the number of comments.

[image]

The problem is, this seems to be updated dynamically by disqus at the beginning of page loading. If you pay close attention to the page when it just opened, it will show "0 comments", but will soon update to "10 comments" (or more by the time you see this).

When I inspected the element, it is a span with class "entry-comment". When I use `rvest` to scrape it though, I get the value "0 comments" even though in the element inspector in my browser it shows "10 comments".

Is there a way to solve this using `rvest`? I can imagine a solution with `RSelenium` but I want to avoid that for various reasons.

Comment: those are disqus comments. disqus has an api https://disqus.com/api/docs/

Comment: Hi thanks for the pointer. I'm not familiar with the api, can it be used together with R to scrape the comment count?

Just to put the context, I'm scraping also other info besides the comment count. I hope to be able to scrape the comment count at the same time, rather than separately run a comment count collector and merging the result back with the other scrape data.

Comment: RSelenium is your best bet then. You'll have to pause the loading process to give the Disqus javascript time to work then target the iframes it creates.